# Reflective discovery of an inner class in an API

Tags: java, api

Let me ask you, as this bothers me for quite a while but appears to be subjectively the best solution for my problem, **if reflective discovery of an inner class for API purposes is that bad idea**?

First, let me explain what I mean by saying "reflective discovery" and all that stuff.

I am sketching an API for a Java database system, that'll be centered around block-based entities (don't ask me what that means - that's a long story), and those *entities* can be read and returned to the Java code as objects subclassed from the `Entity` class.

I have an `Entity.Factory` class, that, by means of fluent interfaces, takes a `Class<? extends Entity>` argument and then, uses an instance of `Section.Builder`, `Property.Builder`, or whatever builder the entity has, to put it into the back-end storage.

The idea about registering all entity types and their builders just doesn't appeal to me, so I thought that the closest solution to the problem that'd suffice my design needs would be to discover, using reflection, all inner classes of `Entity` classes and find one that's called `Builder`.

Looking for some expert insight :) And if I missed some important design details (which could happen as I tried to make this question as concise as possible), just tell me and I'll add them.

Comment: Reflection in user-level code is typically a code smell: try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking at the problem the wrong way.

You shouldn't start from a subclass of Entity and find the associated Builder by reflection.  Instead, you should start from an instance of a Builder and let it build the Entity you want.

I don't know how you use your factory.  But for example, instead of calling factory.create(Section.class) you could call factory.create(new Section.Builder()).  Would that make sense?